# Creating response object Jersey jax-rs

Tags: java, json, jersey, jax-rs

I am calling API inside the for loop. I want to return response for every time loop was ran. for that I create list of Response object but it started throwing Http 500 error.

so if `jsonArray.size()` is value is 3 I want to call API 3 times. Everytime it is returning response object. I want to create array of response and return it to client. But it throws exception.

```
       @GET
       public Response callAPI() {
           Client client=ClientBuilder.newClient();
           WebTarget webTarget = client.target(baseUrl);
            Response response=null;
           for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.size(); i++)
            {
                response  = webtarget.path("bots").path(/api/dynamicEntity).path(i)
                .path("dynamicEntities").request().header("Authorization", "Bearer " + ConnectionUtil.getToken())
                .get(Response.class);
            }
           return response;
}
```

This code works file. I actually want to return array of response. so if I create Response []response and store the result in array and return it, it throws something called marshal exception.I want to store output of this into Array of response and send it to postman.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is with the server side trying to parse the response array before send to client, and failing, because you can't send a array of `Response`, the response for an http request can be just one, what you can do is, mount a json object with the response of each request inside the loop, then send the json string inside of a `Response` object back to the client.